# I am getting the message ‘QTableWidget.setModel() is a private method’

Tags: python

I am attempting to make a page using Qt Designer with a two column table.  One of the columns will be a drag and drop from a windows file listing and the second column is one of the Metafile items from the dropped file.  The files are .mp3 and .wmf files and the Metafile item is comment.  The file is then sent to QMediaPlayer.  I am getting the message `QTableWidget.setModel() is a private method`.  I would appreciate some insite, and a suggested correction.

```
class PlayTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, playlist, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlayTableModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.playlist = playlist

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            media = self.playlist.media(index.row())
            return media.canonicalUrl().fileName()

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self.playlist.mediaCount()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.error.connect(self.erroralert)
        self.player.play()
        # Setup the playlist.
        self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
        self.player.setPlaylist(self.playlist)

        # Connect control buttons/slides for media player.
        self.playButton.pressed.connect(self.player.play)
        self.pauseButton.pressed.connect(self.player.pause)
        self.stopButton.pressed.connect(self.player.stop)
        self.volumeSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.player.setVolume)
        self.clockButton.toggled.connect(self.toggle_clock)
        self.changeDanceStyleButton.toggled.connect(self.change_ds)
        # self.clock.state.connect(self.clockButton.setChecked)
        self.previousButton.pressed.connect(self.playlist.previous)
        self.nextButton.pressed.connect(self.playlist.next)
        self.model = PlayTableModel(self.playlist)



# next line gets error QTableWidget.setModel() is a private method
        self.playTableView.setModel(self.model)



        self.playlist.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.playTable_position_changed)
        selection_model = self.playTableView.selectionModel()
        selection_model.selectionChanged.connect(self.playTable_selection_changed)
        self.player.durationChanged.connect(self.update_duration)
        self.player.positionChanged.connect(self.update_position)
        self.timeSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.player.setPosition)
        self.open_file_action.triggered.connect(self.open_file)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.show()
```

Comment: The problem is as stated in the error message, you cannot call a private method from outside the base class. You should check the documentation for the class you are trying to subclass, to check what methods are available.